# Does ejabberd support DB Level clustering on NOSQL RIak?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, riak

I am working on chat app. I have two ejabberd nodes node1@domain.com and node2@domain.com  if i will do master-master clustering between nodes and each nodes have their own riak server if node1 riak server goes down then how node1 transfer request to node2? Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how it is supposed to work. If you deploy with Riak, you are supposed to have a dedicated Riak infrastructure. Moreover, having only two Riak nodes does not make sense: You need at least 5 Riak nodes to start getting the benefits of using Riak (In term of redundancy / Availability of data).

ejabberd is supposed to refer to the Riak cluster as a whole, single DNS name as Riak is supposed to be configured with a load balancer, like for example HAProxy: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/configs/load-balancing-proxy/

Comment: does single ejabberd node can have more than one riak instance if yes then what i have  to do in ejabberd configuration file?

Comment: You are not supposed to match ejabberd node with ejabberd instances. Riak database cluster is one infrastructure that is leverage by ejabberd. Both can be managed independentlyt by having all ejabberd nodes point to the Riak cluster as a whole. You are suppose to have a load balancer in front of your Riak instance. You should read Riak documentation: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/configs/load-balancing-proxy/