# Connection disconnect riak within ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, riak

I have working on an IM app using ejabberd server with riak backend for offline message it give the following error-

```
** Function: count_by_index
** Table: offline_msg
** Index = <<"us">>
** Key: {<<"917280122322">>,<<"domain.com">>}
** Error: {error,disconnected}
20:35:46.340 [error] database error:
** Function: put
** Record = {offline_msg,
                {<<"917280122322">>,<<"domain.com">>},
                {1450,883146,339993},
                never,
                {jid,<<"917575757575">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<"Smack">>,
                    <<"917575757575">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<"Smack">>},
                {jid,<<"917280122322">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<>>,
                    <<"917280122322">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<>>},
                {xmlel,<<"message">>,
                    [{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},
                     {<<"to">>,<<"917280122322@domain.com">>},
                     {<<"id">>,<<"g8GdH-18">>},
                     {<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],
                    [{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"igivonof">>}]}]}}
** Index info = [{i,{1450,883146,339993}},
                 {'2i',[{<<"us">>,{<<"917080122321">>,<<"domain.com">>}}]}]
** Error: {error,disconnected}
```

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Riak is closing the connection. You need to post the reason of Riak disconnect by looking at Riak log file.

Comment: As your question seems related to previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430530/does-ejabberd-support-db-level-clustering-on-nosql-riak it is also possible that your Riak load balancer is badly configured and thus close the Riak connection.